# phpDocumentor - List of available values for constant

Tags: php, documentation, phpdoc

I am writing API client and I want to define default value for one parameter via constant. Now I have it like this:

```
/**
 * Available: val_1|val_3|val_3|val_4|val_5
 * 
 * @var string
 */
const MY_DEFAULT_VALUE = 'val_1';
```

But I am not sure if this usage of "enum" is correct. I found how to [do it with method parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6476888/phpdocumentor-how-to-document-available-options-for-string-parameter), but this is not the same problem. Definition of my method is:

```
public function callApi($someParam, $anotherParam = self::MY_DEFAULT_VALUE)
```

Is there any standard about this? Thanks a lot.

**EDIT:** I will stop using abstract values and parameters and I'll try to explain it on specific example which I am solving... I am calling API with method `setLanguage()` which has optional parameter `$lang`. Snippet of my code:

```
const DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = 'ENG';
// ...
public function setLanguage($lang = self::DEFAULT_LANGUAGE)
```

But API, which I am calling, accept only some languages. Basicaly, what I want to tell to other programmers in comment is: "*Ok, so you want to change default language, but note that only these values are valid.*". This is nothing critical and I think my currect solution is clear enough too:

```
/**
 * Available: ENG|ITA|FRA|DEU|ESP
 * 
 * @var string
 */
const DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = 'ENG';
```

I was just wondering, if there is some "good practice" about this.

Comment: I'm very confused.  If the constant is hardcoded to val_1, how is it possible that other values (val_3 etc) could be utilized here?

Comment: First post edited, hope it's more clear now what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any time I need a specified enumeration of possible values, I'll always use individual constants to explicitly define *all* of them, e.g. `const VALUE_1 = 'val_1';`, `const VALUE_2 = 'val_2';`.

As for identifying what a default value should be, I agree with your approach of just having that second argument in `callApi()` to set what the default would be (`callApi()`), but to do so by using one of the actual constants rather than having another "default" constant that just points to one of the value constants.  That way, you can set the main default in your base class, and if child classes want to choose their own defaults, they simply override the method.

Also, this allows you to specifically mention those various argument options in the `@param` tag in the docblock for `callApi()`.

Lastly, I'd suggest setting the constant values to simply be integers rather than strings.  That way, since the values themselves will not be particularly informative, callers will be more likely to use the constant names when they do `callApi()`, thus making their own code more readable and less likely to pass unexpected values.

Comment: Look at my first post, I add more specific example of what I am solving, I don't see advantage in creating multiple constants, because you have to add/delete it when some other language appears in API (and let's say, there will be more than 10, 20, 50... supported values).

Comment: I actually learned the "multiple constants for enumerations" thing as a best practice found in many PHP extensions. It makes my code clearer when I have to compare caller's input with my own enumerations, as I can compare directly to the constant rather than doing any extra massaging of their value to try to help them, e.g. uppercase their string to match mine. I expect them to write the constant itself in their code, thus it should match up exactly in my method's code.

Comment: I was thinking about it and you are right, make constant for every available item is maybe most clear way, because you can directly see that default value of some parameter is `self::DEFAULT_LANGUAGE_ENG` and you don't have to check what is it's current value. Thanks